# Animating scale of edge loop to cover texture, not stretch

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, uv

I have a circle with a inner loopcut, and would like to be able to scale the ring without affecting the UV texture on the circle. Currently it warps it, as Blender tries to fit the UV to the (now thinner) ring.

I also need the ability to animate the scale of the inner loop.

[image: Textured View]
[image: UV Map]

When scaling the inner ring, I'd like it to simply "crop" the outer UV texture, instead of "squashing" it.

[image: "Squashed" texture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Edge Slide for editting - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> > Edge Slide

In the operator panel check the Correct UVs option:

[image]

This will crop the outer ring. For the inner ring use different material

[image]

If you want this effect in an shapekeys animation it wont work since they do not affect UV coords. You would have to use a UV Project modifier for the outer rim material:

- add an empty

  [image]
- and setup the modifier for the circle like this:

  [image]

Now it should work also with shapekeys

Comment: Is it possible to make this into a shape key or animate it? **Edit**: It looks like this doesn't work, as it does not enlarge the colored area, but moves the UV map so it looks the same. I'd like to be able to scale the "iris" so that it "covers" the outer rings.

Comment: I added what to do with the inner ring. Shapekeys doesnt effect UVs so no, not possible. You would have to use some different kind of mapping for outer rim - like UV project modifier

Comment: Could yo uprovide an example of using the UV project modifier? I didn't think I could apply it to only part of the mesh.

Comment: There you go, the Override Image and Empty are the key.

Comment: @jackwilsdon please ask that as a new question